# Why grep doesn't match "\<\-v\>"

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to grep the manual page of gcc for the option '-v'.

`man gcc | grep -w '\-v'`  works. But I wanted to use regex.

However the following line doesn't match '-v' at the beginning of a word, as I expected:

```
grep '\<-v' <<<$'-v'
```

Why?

Comment: Because `-` is not a word character, so it can never be the beginning of a word.

Comment: btw, looks like you want to extract information about options from man pages, see https://explainshell.com/ or my own shell script https://github.com/learnbyexample/command_help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word boundary escape sequences differ slightly from `-w` option, from `man grep`

> -w, --word-regexp
>
> Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that  form whole words.  The test is that the matching
>   substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.
>   Similarly,  it  must  be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.
>   Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

whereas, word boundaries in regex will only come into play if there are word characters

```
$ # this fails because there is no word boundary between space and +
$ # assumes \b is supported, like GNU grep
$ echo '2 +3 = 5' | grep '\b+3\b'
$ # this works as -w only ensures that there are no surrounding word characters
$ echo '2 +3 = 5' | grep -w '+3'
2 +3 = 5

$ # doesn't work as , isn't at start of word boundary
$ echo 'hi, 2 one' | grep '\<, 2\>'
$ # won't match as there are word characters before ,
$ echo 'hi, 2 one' | grep -w ', 2'
$ # works as \b matches both edges and , is at end of word after i
$ echo 'hi, 2 one' | grep '\b, 2\b'
hi, 2 one
```